# Packet Loss during Ping

Tags: networking, ping

I'd like to know what causes Packet Loss in this case. Either a Machine is ONLINE & all the packets are received or its OFFLINE and none of the packets are received.So unless there was some intermittent network issue , what other reasons could there be for a 25% Loss ?

```
E:\folder>ping 172.16.196.136

Pinging 172.16.196.136 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.16.196.136: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.16.196.136: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127
Reply from 172.16.196.136: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=127

Ping statistics for 172.16.196.136:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: "intermittent network issue" sums up a LOT of different possible problems. Considering the use of 172.16.x.x, is it safe to assume this is an on-network ping across a single switch? Or is there more to this topography? What type of routing our you using? Dynamic protocols can cause random loss if there are null routes or other routing pitfalls on the network. You need to be much more specific about the path you are trying to ping across.

Comment: I'm trying to ping a machine which is on the same network my IP address is 172.16.192.157. If the first two values (172.16) are the same , does that mean same network ? How to find out what routing protocol I'm using ?

Comment: Is either of the machines using wireless?

Comment: Type a [pathping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PathPing). 

    Pathping is a TCP/IP based utility (command-line tool) that provides useful information about network Latency and Packet Loss at intermediate hops between a source address and a destination address.

    It does this by sending "echo request" packets via ICMP and analyzing the results.